Why hashing when generating account from public key?
When producing an account out of public key it's a common approach to hash the latter multiple times (sometimes using different algos) before encoding and taking a portion of the product. Is this done to protect accounts against collisions? Are there any known attacks exploiting the potential pub key => account vulnerabilities? I can't think of any myself as on my understanding any transactions would require possession of the private key, but would be interested to know more about the subject.

What kind of accounts would this be?

@MaartenBodewes I'd hope it's a website account authenticated with a FIDO passkey.

I guess the OP is referring to PKH style BTC addresses, where hashing the pubkey is a way to avoid pubkey in UTXO (UTXOs can live on blockchain for long time before being spent: it should be impossible to get privkey from pubkey, but implementation bugs in wallet could make this easier than computationally stated). In a non-postquantum algos world could also give some sort of quantum attack resistance. However new addresses style, like taproot, don't use anymore hashing to be able to use ECC structure to get additional funcs.

@Maarten - Bitcoin for example - https://kf106.medium.com/interesting-addresses-on-the-bitcoin-blockchain-e0956f06ec01#:~:text=The%20Bitcoin%20address%20is%20generated,any%20other%20valid%20bitcoin%20address.

@baro77 thanks extra protection makes sense... Basically having that shorter token (aka account) and a public key you can definitively tell if the account is for the public key but not vice versa.
